# Считывание определенной строчки из текстового файла

Tags: c++, fstream

Вот, у меня есть текстовый файл, в котором содержится строчка, с информацией о счете - имя Лёха фамилия Табуретов номер счета 73837728. Эти данные зашифрованный в таком виде:

```
|73837728#nЛёха#snТабуретов.
```

Теперь задача: мне нужно получить доступ к фрагменту строки с фамилией этого человека, не выгружая всю информацию из файла, т.к. там может быть много такой информации и выгружать килобайты текстовой информации и сохранять в строку как то неправильно. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну так читай построчно, пока не доберёшься до нужных данных... других вариантов как бы не предусмотрено...

Comment: А как переходит со строки на строку?

Comment: А не пофиг? считывайте ПОСТРОЧНО, а не бинарно.

Comment: Я понял, а как переходить на следующую строку, или считывать 2, 3 и др. строки?

Comment: Оно само перейдет